# How to use OCMock to return different result base on different argument

Tags: ocmock

I am trying to mock different method return when passing different argument for the same method.

```
self.myMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyClass class]];
[[[self.myMock expect] andReturnValue:5] myStaticMethod:3];
[[[self.myMock expect] andReturnValue:10] myStaticMethod:6];
```

But it only takes the first one, when argument is 3 then return 5, and when argument is 6, it return nil instead of 10.  Does anyone know whether is a way to test this?

the real code:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)convertChildStringToChildDic:(NSString*)strchildren
{
    NSArray *kididarray = [strchildren componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    //处理小孩信息
    /*children =             (
     {
     avatarSmall = "<null>";
     currentStatus = 0;
     displayName = stu1;
     "id_str" = "70938032-3811-e411-946a-005056c00008";
     title = Child;
     }
     )*/
    NSMutableArray *rstchildarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    for (NSString *enrollment_id in kididarray) {
        if (enrollment_id.length <= 0) {
            continue;
        }
        **NSMutableDictionary *mdic = [[RoomInfoManager sharedManager] getKidDictionaryByID:enrollment_id];**

        [mdic setValue:enrollment_id forKey:@"id_str"];
        if (mdic != nil) {
            [rstchildarray addObject:mdic];
        }
    }
    return rstchildarray;
}
```

Test:

```
-(void) testconvertChildStringToChildDic_InvalidAgruments {
    NSMutableDictionary *childdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    childdic[@"id"] = @"josh";

    NSMutableDictionary *childdic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    childdic1[@"id"] = @"joy";


    id mockRIM = OCMClassMock([RoomInfoManager class]);
    **OCMStub([mockRIM getKidDictionaryByID:@"josh"]).andReturn(childdic);
    **OCMStub([mockRIM getKidDictionaryByID:@"joy"]).andReturn(childdic1);****


    RoomInfoManager *roomInfoMgr = [RoomInfoManager alloc];
    id mockPartialRIM = OCMPartialMock(roomInfoMgr);

    OCMExpect([mockPartialRIM sharedManager]).andReturn(mockRIM); // use expect

    NSString *childStr = @"josh,joy";
    NSMutableArray *childarray = [[ReportOperator alloc] convertChildStringToChildDic:childStr];

    NSDictionary *childrenArraydic = @{@"id" : @"josh", @"id_str": @"josh"};
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:childrenArraydic, nil];

    [mockPartialRIM verify]; // verify expect,验证该对像是否被调用。

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(childarray, resultArray);
}
```

the second call

```
OCMStub([mockRIM getKidDictionaryByID:@"joy"]).andReturn(childdic1);
```

does not seem take effect and return nil instead.

Comment: This should work exactly like you describe. Can you post a self-contained example that demonstrates the behaviour you are seeing? I mean, can you include a failing unit test that doesn't depend on classes you cannot share.

Comment: I update the code above and hope it is clear now what I am asking. Thanks!

Comment: Can you write a separate test method to verify that you are correct in assuming the stubbed value in `OCMStub([mockRIM getKidDictionaryByID:@"joy"]).andReturn(childdic1);` is not being returned? The current test seems to be expecting that the return value is nil, so it would be helpful to see the problem reduced to checking whether or not `getKidDictionaryByID` returns an NSMutableDictionary on the correct parameter.